# Why im getting Exception- Not enough variables available to expand in Spring Rest URI call?

Tags: spring, rest, encodeuricomponent

im working on a rest API call related to Payments. But i encountered with an exception. I know this comes due to setting parameters to the rest uri.

```
String uri = "https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/52/merchant/{merchantId}/order/{orderId}/transaction/{transactionId}";
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> uriVars = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    uriVars.add("merchantId", _paymentInstrument.getAcquirerMid());
    uriVars.add("orderId", _paymentInstrument.getOrderId().toString());
    uriVars.add("transactionId", _paymentInstrument.getTargetTransactionId().toString());
    String uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
            .queryParams(uriVars).build().toUriString();
    VoidRequest voidRequest = 
createVoidRequest(_paymentInstrument.getTargetTransactionId());
    HttpEntity<VoidRequest> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(voidRequest, headers); 
ResponseEntity<TransactionResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, TransactionResponse.class);
```

Exception im getting is Using RestTemplate in Spring. Exception- Not enough variables available to expand "merchantId".

Comment: can you please confirm once if there are special characters in merchant id

Comment: @AkshayKhopkar. No its just a string value.